# I can't get HTTPS requests on apache

Tags: php, apache, https, rhel, telegram-bot

I'm in trouble with Apache HTTPS server on RHEL.

I'm using telegram webhook API. What I want to do that is, when a message is sent to a group or telegram bot itself it triggers the web page which I set with the webhook API.

My API request:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[MY_BOT_TOKEN]/setWebHook

=> im sending url=bot.test.blabla.com/dosomething.php with POST method
```

My certificate is valid, I tested it with opening a new browser page and details said that the "certificate is valid".

However, interesting part is when I type `tcpdump -i eth0 port 443 -vv >> /root/dump.dump` to listen to my 443 port, the packages are coming from IP address that I expected. But Apache does not do anything.

I also tested the API, with another server and it does what it is expected.

There is no iptables or TCP wrapper configuration on my server

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the apache logs to see if the request is even being seen by apache? 
/var/log/httpd/error_log
/var/log/httpd/access_log

Comment: unfortunatelly, there is no log on theese files

Comment: and this is one of the line log on my /root/dump.dump file     14:38:08.652045 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 49, id 40206, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    149.154.167.226.52375 > localhost.localdomain.https: Flags [.], cksum 0xbe2b (correct), seq 347, ack 1823, win 33, options [nop,nop,TS val 2874453536 ecr 3425403650], length 0